# Adobe Air - How to style a textbox so it only has the bottom border line

Tags: css, actionscript-3, air, adobe

I have a form that the user needs to fill out. The form contains TextInput. The default Adobe Air textboxes are old school styled. I want to modify them so they look more modern. How can I style a textbox so it only has the bottom border line and its fill color is white?

Thanks!

Avi

Comment: There's no such thing as Adobe AIR textbox. There's Flash TextField and related and then there's Flex. There are literally no object called textbox in Adobe AIR and Flash.

Comment: You are of course right. I am reffering to TextArea or in a Form TextInput. Modified my question. Thanks.

Comment: Alright but still are those Flex components? Flash IDE components? etc ...

Comment: Please remove css from your tag, the 2 person who posted answers did not bother reading your question and posted a css answer which has nothing to do with your question. Fix that and ask those 2 persons to remove their unrelated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here ([Adobe AIR brings Advanced CSS3 Support to the Desktop](http://www.css3.info/adobe-air-2-brings-advanced-css3-support-to-the-desktop/)), Adobe AIR now supports CSS3.

Also refer this ([Manipulating an HTML stylesheet from ActionScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f09.html)).

Use CSS `border`.

- Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/5qou5aaw/). **(bottom border = red)**

Here is the snippet.

```css
input,
textarea {
  border-bottom: red 2px solid;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' />
<br>
<textarea></textarea>
```

- Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/5qou5aaw/1/). **(only bottom border = red)**

Here is the snippet.

```css
input, textarea {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: red 2px solid;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' /><br>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi Shrinivas, Thanks. I've stated in the subject that I am specifically looking for a solution for Adobe Air (ActionScript) textbox. Can this help? thanks.

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla Are you familiar with AIR? Yes, AIR supports HTML and has since it was created, but that doesn't mean you can use "advanced CSS3" within ActionScript or Flex, which is what the OP is asking. It's a completely different CSS used in that context.

Answer (score 0):

```
Shrinivas answer will put a border on the bottom but still shows borders on the side.
```

If you wanted to hide them you could also color the side borders the same as the background.
On a white background, this will essentially hide the sides and top borders.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6swdpe8y/

```
input{
        border-right: white 2px solid;
        border-left: white 2px solid;
        border-top: white 2px solid;
        background: white;
    }

<input type='text' />
```

Comment: Thanks squinny, However I was specifically asking for Adobe Air (ActionScript) textbox styling. Any idea how to apply it there? Thanks!